# Get resource hex/ascii \n\r value not converted one

Tags: c#, xml, string, ascii, resx

Greeting,

We have some translation stored in a resx file which contains a break line similar to:

**"This is a Test
 & or something similar. "**
[image]

There are ~50 devs in our project and from time to time Visual studio corrects the translation into
**"This is a Test
& or something similar. " causing our pipeline to fail (long story)**
[image]

Now my goal is to write a test and to ensure that the translations are not "corrupted", but I found no way to get the actual hex or ASCII value of the string above.
It always comes as \n\r .

I also want to mention that I would like not to change the current behavior of the app, only to get the proper ASCII or hex from the resource

This is what I would like to get from the resx file using: GetString or similar

- &# xA;&# xD;
- &# 13;&# 10;

  ```
    [TestMethod]
   public void Test()
   {
       // Arrange
       var x = ToLiteral("This is a Test&#13;&#10; &amp;& or something similar.");

       // Act
       var xExpected = ToLiteral(Resources.Something.Some_Title);

       // Assert
       x.ShouldBe(xExpected );               
   }

   private static string ToLiteral(string valueTextForCompiler)
   {
       return Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplay.FormatLiteral(valueTextForCompiler, false);
   }
  ```

Comment: Use the string Trim() method which will remove white characters at ends of string.

Comment: The Windows line-break sequence should be `\r\n`, which would match your `&#13;&#10;` from your code and second screenshot, but not the `&#xA;&#xD;` from your first screenshot.

Comment: Also note you have an unescaped `&` in your second screenshot and your code.

Comment: That was just an example, the problem is i want &#13;&#10; or  &#xA;&#xD; not \r\n when i use res.GetString(myString)